# Perl 6: Lookahead with capture

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, raku

I'm attempting to write a Perl 6 regex for [this code-golf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/189859/76162) that splits a string with the rules:

- Sequences of the same character with length 3 or less will be grouped together
- But 4 or more will result in the first two being grouped before checking the rest

For example:

```
66667888    -> '66', '66, '7', '888'
19999999179 -> '1', '99', '99', '999', '1', '7', '9'
```

I thought the regex `m:g/(.)[$0$0<!$0>|$0?]/` would work, but using a capture in the negative lookahead seems to break it, and I can't figure out how to use it properly.

Depending on how I use it, it either [loops forever](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVKhOtcqXV9DTzNaxUDFwEZRxcCuRsXAPla/VkPJ0BICDM0tlTT//wcA), throws the [error](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVKhOtcqXV9DTzNaxUDFwEZRxcCuRsXAPla/VkPJEgIMzS2VNP//BwA) `Cannot resolve caller INTERPOLATE_ASSERTION`, or [returns the wrong result](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBydASAgzNLZUU6uoUcq3S9TX0NKNVDFQMbBRVDOxqVAzsY/X//wcA). Is there a proper way to use captures in lookaheads, or is this a bug?

Comment: Why does `6666` because `66` and `66` rather than `666` and `6`, given that your rule states that sequences of 3 or less will be grouped together?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `But 4 or more will result in the first two being grouped before checking the rest`. So 4 in a row will be grouped as 2 and 2, not 3 and 1, while 5 will be 2 then 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [*Capturing*](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Capturing) section you need to use a code block to make these backreferences visible inside a regex:

> These capture variables are only available outside the regex...
>   In order to make them available inside the regex, you need to insert a code block behind the match; this code block may be empty if there's nothing meaningful to do

Use

```
given "19999999179" {
  for m:g/(.) {} :my $c = $0; ([ $c$c<!$c> | $c? ])/  -> $match {
    say ~$match;
  }
}
```

Results:

```
1
99
99
999
1
7
9
```

See the [Perl6 demo](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z89syw1T0HJ0BICDM0tlRSquRQU0vKLFHKt0vU19DQVqmsVrHIrFVSSFWwVVAysFTSigWyVZBtFlWQ7hRog214hVlNfQUHXTkElN7EkOQNsgoJCcWKlQh1ExBooUMtV@/8/AA).

In this scenario, you may contract the pattern to `m:g/(.) {} [ $0$0<!$0> | $0? ]/`:

```
my @matches;
given "19999999179" {
  for m:g/(.) {} [ $0$0<!$0> | $0? ]/ -> $match {
    @matches.push: (~$match);
  }
}
say @matches;
```

Results in `[1 99 99 999 1 7 9]`.

See [this Perl6 demo](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/58rt1LBITexJDkjtdiaKz2zLDVPQcnQEgIMzS2VFKq5FBTS8osUcq3S9TX0NBWqaxWiFVQMVAxsFFUM7BRqgGx7hVh9BV07BRWwQWAdCnBT9QpKizOsFDTqILKa1kDZWq5aruJEZJu5/v8HAA).

Comment: Ah interesting. For golfing purposes though, you can just insert the `{}` after the capture to force the assignment, as long as you're not doing another capture. [Demo](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z89syw1T0HJ0BICDM0tlRSquRQU0vKLFHKt0vU19DSra6NVDFQMbBRVDOxqVAzsY/UVFHTtFFRyE0uSM8CKFRSKEysV6iAi1kCBWq7a//8B)

Comment: FYI, for golfing and perhaps a little more speed and readability you can simplify to `m:g/(.) $0? [ $0 {} <!$0> ]? /`, dropping a `$0` and a `|` alternation (a better golf), and putting the `{}` immediately before the construct that currently requires it (the `<!$0>`) for arguably better readability and perhaps a tiny speed up.

Comment: Yes, the original pattern can be translated (for the regex "debug" purpose) into [`(.)(?:\1\1(?!\1)|\1?)`](https://regex101.com/r/UoIy7N/2) Perl 5 regex, that really can be improved a little bit to [`(.)\1?(?:\1(?!\1))?`](https://regex101.com/r/UoIy7N/2) (PCRE test shows 6 steps less for the string in question). So, the `m:g/(.) $0? [ $0 {} <!$0> ]? /` regex is OK here.